# Latitude and longitude inherit missing

Tags: 6, location

I have adapted a module from a whole bunch of code, but I still cannot inherit the nodes latitude and longitude location from the currently logged in user. The problem is the parent case locpick, and I don't know how to handle the parent.

```
<?php

function location_alter($argument) {
  global $user;
  $location_alter = array();

  $uid = $user->uid;
  $location_alter = user_load($uid);
  $location_alter = $location_alter->location;

  return $location_alter[$argument];
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_locationapi().
 */
function locnodeauthor_locationapi(&$obj, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL, $a5 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'field_expand':
      switch ($a3) {
        case 'name':
          return array(
            '#type'           => 'textfield',
            '#title'          => t('Location name'),
            '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('name'),
            '#size'           => 64,
            '#maxlength'      => 64,
            '#description'    => t('e.g. a place of business, venue, meeting point'),
            '#attributes'     => NULL,
            '#required'       => ($a4 == 2),
          );

        case 'street':
          return array(
            '#type'           => 'textfield',
            '#title'          => t('Street'),
            '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('street'),
            '#size'           => 64,
            '#maxlength'      => 64,
            '#required'       => ($a4 == 2),
          );

        // Additional is linked to street.
        case 'additional':
          return array(
            '#type'           => 'textfield',
            '#title'          => t('Additional'),
            '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('additional'),
            '#size'           => 64,
            '#maxlength'      => 64,
            // Required is forced OFF because this is technically part of street.
          );

        case 'city':
          return array(
            '#type'           => 'textfield',
            '#title'          => t('City'),
            '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('city'),
            '#size'           => 64,
            '#maxlength'      => 64,
            '#description'    => NULL,
            '#attributes'     => NULL,
            '#required'       => ($a4 == 2),
          );

        case 'province':
          drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'location') .'/location_autocomplete.js');
          $country = $a5['country'] ? $a5['country'] : variable_get('location_default_country', 'us');
          return array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('State/Province'),
            '#autocomplete_path' => 'location/autocomplete/'. $country,
            '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('province'),
            '#size' => 64,
            '#maxlength' => 64,
            '#description' => NULL,
            // Used by province autocompletion js.
            '#attributes' => array('class' => array('location_auto_province')),
            '#required' => ($a4 == 2),
          );

        case 'country':
          // Force default.
          if ($a4 == 4) {
            return array(
              '#type' => 'value',
              '#value' => variable_get('location_default_country', 'us'),
            );
          }
          else {
            $options = array_merge(array('' => t('Please select'), 'xx' => 'NOT LISTED'), location_get_iso3166_list());
            return array(
              '#type'           => 'select',
              '#title'          => t('Country'),
              '#default_value'  => $obj,
              '#options'        => $options,
              '#description'    => NULL,
              '#required'       => ($a4 == 2),
              // Used by province autocompletion js.
              '#attributes'     => array('class' => array('location_auto_country')),
            );
          }
          break;

        case 'postal_code':
          return array(
            '#type'           => 'textfield',
            '#title'          => t('Postal code'),
            '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('postal_code'),//$location_alter['postal_code'],//location_alter('postal_code'),
            '#size'           => 16,
            '#maxlength'      => 16,
            '#required'       => ($a4 == 2),
          );
      }
      break;

    case 'isunchanged':
      switch ($a3) {
        case 'lid':
          // Consider 0, NULL, and FALSE to be equivilent.
          if (empty($obj[$a3]) && empty($a4)) {
            return TRUE;
          }
          break;

          case 'country':
            // Consider '  ' and '' to be equivilent, due to us storing country
            // as char(2) in the database.
            if (trim($obj[$a3]) == trim($a4)) {
              return TRUE;
            }
            break;

          case 'province_name':
          case 'country_name':
          case 'map_link':
          case 'coords':
            // Always considered unchanged.
            return TRUE;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could try outputting the parent's properties? A `var_dump()` goes a long way.